# Limit CrmSvcUtil to create only the code needed for my solution

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

Here is what I doing now

```
CrmSvcUtil.exe /codeCustomization:"Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration.CodeCustomization,Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration" /url:http://pcrm/Adzz/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc /out:Xrm.cs /username:xxxx /password:xxxx /domain:xxxx /namespace:xxxx /serviceContextName:XrmServiceContext
```

When I use the 'CrmSvcUtil' utility - it creates all entities, How can I limit it so only the solution entities will generate code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [Extensions for the Code Generation Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547384.aspx). Interface that should help you is `ICodeWriterFilterService`. There is sample implementation on same page and it points to examples in SDK.

EDIT: For another great example please see Nicknow comment below

Comment: Let me add this link to answer here: http://erikpool.blogspot.com/2011/03/filtering-generated-entities-with.html. I've used the code in that link a bunch.